# PHP Debug in VSCode

Tags: php, linux, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I am trying to get PHP debugging to work in VS code on a Debian system. I have followed several different posts and videos and help files and just can't get it to work. There is conflicting information probably due to different versions of the software?

Here is what I have:

- VS Code 1.65.0
- XAMPP for Linux 8.0.15 (Apache is running)

Installed VS Code extensions
PHP Debug
PHP Intellisense

Installed
xdebug through apt-install (shows version 3.02+2.9.8....)
But if I run phpinfo() I do not see an entry for xdebug
Running the xdebug wizard it says that xdebug is not installed so I followed the steps outlined

```
   download/extract xdebug-3.1.3
   run phpize
   run ./configure
   run cp modules/xdebug.so /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930
```

```
   ^^This gives me an error cp: cannot stat 'modules/xdebug.so' : no such file or directory
```

The instructions also state to add

```
   zend_extension = xdebug
```

In the VS Code, it stated to make the follwing changes:
added below to /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini (php.ini as shown by phpinfo())
(in the Dynamic Extensions section)
zend_extension =xdebug.so (I tried keeping the above one and keeping just this one)

(at the end of the file-not sure where it was supposed to go? But looks like it is in the [opcache] section?

```
xdebug.mode= debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
```

And I tried several other things and still no luck. What info do you need and what do I need to do to get the debugging working?

Thanks

Comment: use this tool https://xdebug.org/wizard to get specific info for your configuration.

Comment: Did you see post where it outlines the steps I took in xdebug.org/wizard?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> download/extract xdebug-3.1.3
> run phpize
> run ./configure
> run cp modules/xdebug.so /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930
> ```

The wizard instructions tell you to run `make` between `run ./configure` and `run cp modules/xdebug.so /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930`

The `make` step is what compiles the extension.